# Calling another constructor within a constructor

Tags: c#, vb.net, constructor

What is the equivalent of the below C# in VB.net?

" A constructor can invoke another constructor in the same object by using the this keyword. Like base, this can be used with or without parameters, and any parameters in the constructor are available as parameters to this, or as part of an expression."

```
public Employee(int weeklySalary, int numberOfWeeks)
    : this(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)
{
}
```

I would suspect:

```
Public Sub New(weeklySalary As Integer, numberOfWeeks As Integer)
    Me.New(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)
End Sub
```

...but this does not work the same.

Comment: It should be called like you are doing in your code, what doesn't work ?, do you have single parameter constructor ?

Comment: I always use mybase.new

Comment: It seems to work for me. What about it doesn't work the same?

Comment: @Habib Maybe I am not understanding what is supposed to happen when you instantiate this class. Where would I have access to the value of Me.New(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)

Comment: @Sanpopo, `Me.New(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)` means that there is another constructor receiving a single parameter in your class, if you don't have it, you can't call it

Comment: In the C# code, it's calling an `Employee(int)` constructor. In VB, it's trying to call a `New(Integer)` constructor. If that constructor doesn't exist, this won't work.

Comment: @Habib ah..lol Lightbulb moment. I see now, the problem ended up being that the property that was getting set in my `New()` constructor which is set inside `Me.New(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)` was private and not accessible. I was missing the connection, too much going between c# and vb today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Me.New is what you call.  See the following reference http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html.  Its towards the bottom of the page.